# Como usar o declare em uma procedure no MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Estou criando uma procedure de insert no MySQL, mas ao tentar declarar uma variável aparece um erro dizendo:

> "statement incomplete waiting : ;"

Este é o meu código

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `inserirAgente` (
  IN `nome` VARCHAR(60),
  IN `rg` VARCHAR(150), 
  IN `cpf` VARCHAR(150), 
  IN `sexo` VARCHAR(20), 
  IN `escolaridade` VARCHAR(50), 
  IN `dt_nasc` VARCHAR(10),
  IN `dt_admissao` VARCHAR(10), 
  IN `funcao` VARCHAR(30),
  IN `email` VARCHAR(150),
  IN `senha` VARCHAR(150),
  IN `foto` VARCHAR(150),
  IN `estado` CHAR(2), 
  IN `cidade` VARCHAR(30),
  IN `cep` VARCHAR(9), 
  IN `bairro` VARCHAR(30),
  IN `rua` VARCHAR(30),
  IN `numero` INT,
  IN `complemento` VARCHAR(30), 
  IN `tel` VARCHAR(20)
  )
  BEGIN
    declare cod int;
    cod=select max(cod_agente) from agentes;

    INSERT INTO `Agentes`(nome, dt_nasc, rg, cpf, sexo, escolaridade, dt_admissao, funcao, email, senha, foto) 
    VALUES(nome, dt_nasc, rg, cpf, sexo, escolaridade, dt_admissao, funcao, email, senha, foto);

    INSERT INTO `Enderecos`(estado, cidade, cep, bairro, rua, numero, complemento, cod_agente_end)
    VALUES(estado, cidade, cep, bairro, rua, numero, complemento, cod);

    INSERT INTO `Telefones`(cod_agente_tel, tel)
    VALUES(cod, tel);
END
```

Comecei a usar o MySQL há alguns dias e não sei o que está errado.

Answer (score 1):

A cláusula `DECLARE` não inicializa a variável. Quando você o declara, declara o nome da variável, o tipo e um valor padrão, que pode ser inclusive, uma expressão.

Já a cláusula `SET`, é utilizada para inicializar a variável que você declarou anteriormente.

Antão ficaria:

```
SET cod = (select max(cod_agente) from agentes);
```

---

Abaixo segue uma explicação detalhada sobre variáveis.
*Original de Omesh:* https://stackoverflow.com/a/11754790/6378641

Existem basicamente três tipos de variáveis ​​no MySQL:

1. **[Variáveis ​​definidas pelo usuário](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) (prefixadas com @):**

Você pode acessar qualquer variável definida pelo usuário sem declará-la ou inicializá-la. Se você se referir a uma variável que não tenha sido inicializada, ela terá um valor `NULL` e um tipo string.

```
SELECT @var_any_var_name
```

Você pode inicializar uma variável usando a instrução `SET` ou `SELECT`:

```
SET @start = 1, @finish = 10;
```

ou

```
SELECT @start := 1, @finish := 10;

SELECT * FROM places WHERE place BETWEEN @start AND @finish;
```

As variáveis ​​de usuário podem receber um valor de um conjunto limitado de tipos de dados: integer, decimal, floating-point, binary ou nonbinary string, ou valor NULL.

Variáveis ​​definidas pelo usuário são específicas da sessão, ou seja, uma variável de usuário definida por um cliente não pode ser vista ou usada por outros clientes.

Eles podem ser usados ​​em consultas `SELECT` usando [Advanced MySQL user variable techniques](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/).

2. **[Variáveis ​​locais](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) (sem prefixo):**

Variáveis ​​locais precisam ser declaradas usando `DECLARE` antes de acessá-lo.

Eles podem ser usados ​​como variáveis ​​locais e os parâmetros de entrada dentro de um procedimento armazenado:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test(var1 INT) 
BEGIN   
    DECLARE start  INT unsigned DEFAULT 1;  
    DECLARE finish INT unsigned DEFAULT 10;

    SELECT  var1, start, finish;

    SELECT * FROM places WHERE place BETWEEN start AND finish; 
END; //

DELIMITER ;

CALL sp_test(5);
```

Se a cláusula `DEFAULT` estiver faltando, o valor inicial será `NULL`.

O escopo de uma variável local é o bloco `BEGIN ... END` dentro do qual é declarado.

3. **[Variáveis ​​de sistema do servidor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-system-variables.html) (prefixadas com @@):**

O servidor MySQL mantém muitas [variáveis ​​do sistema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html) configuradas para um valor padrão. Eles podem ser do tipo `GLOBAL`, `SESSION` ou `BOTH`.

As variáveis ​​globais afetam a operação geral do servidor, enquanto as variáveis ​​de sessão afetam sua operação para conexões de clientes individuais.

Para ver os valores atuais usados ​​por um servidor em execução, use a instrução `SHOW VARIABLES` ou `SELECT @@var_name`.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%wait_timeout%';

SELECT @@sort_buffer_size;
```

Eles podem ser definidos na inicialização do servidor usando opções na linha de comando ou em um arquivo de opções. A maioria deles pode ser alterada dinamicamente enquanto o servidor está em execução usando `SET GLOBAL` ou `SET SESSION`:

```
-- Sintaxe para definir valor para uma variável global:
SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size=1000000;
SET @@global.sort_buffer_size=1000000;

-- Sintaxe para definir valor para uma variável de sessão:
SET sort_buffer_size=1000000;
SET SESSION sort_buffer_size=1000000;
SET @@sort_buffer_size=1000000;
SET @@local.sort_buffer_size=10000;
```